# Simple firefox extension "not compatible" error in Pale Moon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, palemoon

I'm trying to get a very basic extension working in [Pale Moon](http://www.palemoon.org/) (variation of Firefox).

lib\main.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self");
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.annoyingsite.com",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("script.js")] 
});
```

lib\script.js:

```
document.getElementById("annoyingElement").setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
```

But I get the error:

```
[extension_name] could not be installed because it is not compatible with Pale Moon 24.7.2
```

I've tried reading the CFX docs and looking around on stackoverflow. The only hint I've found is perhaps it's something to do with `minVersion`/`maxVersion` in `install.rdf`, but I haven't got anywhere. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They changed the GUID for Pale Moon. I think it's a stupid move, but I guess it was necessary.

More information here:

[MozillaZine :: Pale Moon has changed its GUID](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=2866589)

[PaleMoonForum :: Extensions and Pale Moon 25](https://forum.palemoon.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=5440)

you have to add this to your install.rdf:

```
  <em:targetApplication><!-- Pale Moon -->
     <Description>
        <em:id>{8de7fcbb-c55c-4fbe-bfc5-fc555c87dbc4}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>25.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>25.*</em:maxVersion>
     </Description>
  </em:targetApplication>
```

So compile your addon to xpi, then rename to zip, then edit install.rdf, add GUID of pale moon, then zip it back up, then rename to xpi